# excel file as job parameter in spring batch

Tags: spring

I have an requirement to use sprint batch in order to bulk upload excel data. user would be importing this file from an UI and service is expected to use this file and import into database. I am new to spring batch and with some analysis was able to infer that we will not be able to send excel file as parameter . Is saving the file to local is only way to read this file ? Is there anyway i can read the incoming file directly using spring batch ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want a user to invoke a Spring service endpoint with a file and then Spring batch job should pick that file up as an input and start job processing.

Yes, this is very much doable and you do not need to explicitly save it to your local yourself.

Here is what I would do:

1. Take the file as an input to a POST endpoint using Spring "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile" object. Let's call this object "file".
2. Then get the input stream from MultipartFile object using "file.getInputStream()".
3. Set this input stream as "resource" to "FlatFileItemReader" object of Spring Batch.

Sample code:

> flatFileItemReader.setResource(new
>   InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()));

Once this is done and you start the Spring batch job, this file will be processed in your job.